# Tests in error:test(org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.filedata.ChunkInputFormatTest)

Tags: java, hadoop, netbeans-7, cloudera, accumulo

When I build the examples-simple maven project included in the accumulo-1.4.3-cdh43.tar.gz

I am using netbeans set to a java platform of jdk1.6.0.32.

I get test failures for Tests in error: test(org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.filedata.ChunkInputFormatTest)

### Here is the output:

### T E S T S

Running org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.filedata.ChunkInputFormatTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.441 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.filedata.ChunkCombinerTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.014 sec
Running org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.filedata.ChunkInputStreamTest
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.297 sec
Running org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.filedata.KeyUtilTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
Running org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.dirlist.CountTest
Max depth              : 3
Time to find max depth : 5 ms
Time to compute counts : 2 ms
Entries scanned        : 30 
Counts inserted        : 4 
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.032 sec

Results :

Tests in error: 
  test(org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.filedata.ChunkInputFormatTest): Found class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but interface was expected
  testErrorOnNextWithoutClose(org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.filedata.ChunkInputFormatTest): Found class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but interface was expected
  testInfoWithoutChunks(org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.filedata.ChunkInputFormatTest): Found class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but interface was expected

Tests run: 15, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0

---

### BUILD FAILURE

Total time: 27.392s
Finished at: Tue Feb 11 07:49:37 PST 2014

### Final Memory: 21M/57M

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.9:test (default-test) on project examples-simple: There are test failures.

Please refer to /usr/lib/accumulo/src/examples/simple/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

The website gives me a url error.

I then went to the surefire reports:

### Test set: org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.filedata.ChunkInputFormatTest

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.441 sec <<< FAILURE!
test(org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.filedata.ChunkInputFormatTest)  Time elapsed: 1.433 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but interface was expected
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.mapreduce.InputFormatBase$RecordReaderBase.initialize(InputFormatBase.java:1108)
        at org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.filedata.ChunkInputFormat$1.initialize(ChunkInputFormat.java:47)
        at org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.filedata.ChunkInputFormatTest.test(ChunkInputFormatTest.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)

I would appreciate knowing if this is just to be ignored or will effect my development work.

thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're still building against a Hadoop2 version (the MR2 variant of cdh4.3 is my guess) which is not compatible with Accumulo 1.4.3.

If you want to use cdh with Accumulo 1.4.3, you'll have to make sure you use their MR1 support otherwise you'll run into incompatibilities.

Comment: Hi Mate, this is what I was told but I am netbeans-ignorant. Cloudera told me that in the  Quick Start 4.4. VM release  of the Accumulo 1.4.x line, you still had to specify the Hadoop 2 profile via a Java system property.
Command line maven would look like this:
$> mvn -Dhadoop.profile=2.0 package
I presume there is some way to specify this in the build options for netbeans, but I am not familiar with that particular IDE help please :-)